# Silverlight 4, How to Dynamic load rows into a data grid based on scrolling?

Tags: datagridview, silverlight-4.0, scroll, dynamic-loading

I have a datagrid and a PagedCollectionView with more than 1000 objects and a pagesize of 100.
How can I add the PagedCollectionView to the datagrid such that when its scroll bar riches the bottom end will add an additional 100 rows to the datagrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manishdalal/archive/2008/10/09/stealth-paging-datagrid.aspx

Comment: yeah good code, although in dotNet but gives ideas how to implement in javascript.